# Histogram vs Bar Graph

Tags: graph, statistics, bar-chart, histogram

I have data for number of patients used to collect the data in a hospital for each day. I want to display them as a graphical representation of number of patients used to collect the data for each week. Which graph is more suitable for this? Histogram or Bar Graph? Please explain the pros and cons of each of them. Also if you find any graph better than them, please tell me and also justify it.

Comment: Do you want to represent the number of patients that are present in a hospital for each week ?

Comment: @Student.py Yeah. That's what I want to visualize